# Angular main module app.js is getting cached , what is needed is a way to make sure it is not when new code is added

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have `app.js`

Decided to add a `Token` to send over in header.

So I added in

```
app.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'M1BBUktUT0tFYk==';
});
```

However, about running site ( it happens to be a asp.net mvc / web api site)   I end up with NOT seeing the code working , and view source , click on app.js and it is NOT there,  **I refresh that app.js in browser and it works then.**

I think that I only have this trouble with asp.net mvc website caching of js and css ..

**What is the best approach to NOT have this caching problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways. Basically what they all do is add a querystring to the end of the script/css. Something like `myScript.js?v={some random number}`

You can use bundling in asp.net mvc. Once the bundle is created, it will add a version number to your scripts/css so each time you run the code you get the latest version. If you check the page source, you will see something like

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=tM7sBY5D-DIWHn61FAscLi2oiu1l1yS8NveURT-p-Ac1"></script>
```

Note the `v=` querystring, this will change each time so you get a new version as the browser thinks its a new file.

What I've just implemented in my mvc application, is to not use bundling but grunt. I add `?ver=<<version>>` to the end of all my js and css script include statements (`<script src="~/Scripts/dist/app/MyApp.min.js?ver=<<version>>"></script?`), and use grunts replace task to replace `<<version>>` with a javascript timestamp.

Important bits from my grunt.js file

```
grunt.initConfig({
    'string-replace': {
      version: {
        files: {
          './Views/Home/Index.cshtml': './Views/Home/Index.cshtml',
          './Views/Search/Index.cshtml': './Views/Search/Index.cshtml'
        },
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            pattern: /s\?ver=[0-9]+/g,
            replacement: 's?ver=<%= version %>'
          }, {
            pattern: /<<version>>/g,
            replacement: '<%= version %>'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
});
grunt.config.set('version', Date.now());
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace']);
```

So the above will replace the `ver` querystring in the Index files listed with the value returned from Date.now()

I'm also using grunt for minifying, copying files, concatenating files, etc. Very powerful once you get the hang of it and doesn't take much to learn.

Comment: Thanks , i appreciate it!

Comment: I use gulp instead of grunt - so i will probably add to my gulp task

Comment: Everyone I talk to seems to be using gulp..... Think it may be time for a switch myself!

Comment: I like it better  "code over configuration"   (gulp vs grunt )